# How to sum the values of second column if the names in the first column matches between two data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes which look like following:

```
df1:

Sample   Digit
AACF-01    6
AACG-01    7
AAKD-01    3
AAIU-01    4

df2:

Sample   Digit
AACF-01    8
AACJ-01    2
AAKD-01    4
AALO-01    5
```

If the names in the first column matches between two data frames sum the values in the second column.

Result should look like the following:

```
Sample   Digit
AACF-01    14
AACG-01     7
AACJ-01     2
AAKD-01     7
AAIU-01     4
AALO-01     5
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bind the rows of the dataset, grouped by 'Sample', get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
       group_by(Sample) %>% 
       summarise(Digit = sum(Digit))
# A tibble: 6 × 2
#    Sample Digit
#    <chr> <int>
#1 AACF-01    14
#2 AACG-01     7
#3 AACJ-01     2
#4 AAIU-01     4
#5 AAKD-01     7
#6 AALO-01     5
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[, .(Digit = sum(Digit)), .(Sample)]
#    Sample Digit
#1: AACF-01    14
#2: AACG-01     7
#3: AAKD-01     7
#4: AAIU-01     4
#5: AACJ-01     2
#6: AALO-01     5
```

---

Or using `base R` to avoid

```
aggregate(.~Sample, rbind(df1, df2), sum)
#    Sample Digit
#1 AACF-01    14
#2 AACG-01     7
#3 AACJ-01     2
#4 AAIU-01     4
#5 AAKD-01     7
#6 AALO-01     5
```